# disable jquery above a certain viewport size

Tags: jquery

I'm basically looking to disable a jquery function above a certain viewport size. I've got it set up that when a link in the nav is clicked the nav, then scrolls out of view. I don't think it's necessary that anyone understands exactly what the function is doing, just that i only want it to work below a certain viewport size. The problem I have is that it's doing this on larger viewports which I don't want. Any help would be much appreciated

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".trigger , .close").click(function(){
             $(".showing").slideToggle("slow");   
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After determining the viewport size you can turn the event off.

```
if(viewportSize > 1200){
    $(".trigger, .close").off("click");
}
```

Or

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger , .close").click(function(){

         if(viewportSize > 1200){
             return;
         }

         $(".showing").slideToggle("slow");   
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATED:** I tested the possible solution of using off() to disable the event triggering in certain conditions.

**UPDATED:** using window viewport size-check to disable or re-enable slideToggle. You can lower or increase the timeout (now set to 50) if you want the window size to be detected at different intervals based on how reactive you want the code to run. Run the code sample in full size or the window resize will not be triggered.

```js
//change this value to trigger
        var maxWidth = 900;

        var assignBehaviourToMenuItems = function($in_target){

            $in_target.find('.trigger').each(function(){
                var $menuItem = $(this);
                $menuItem.on('click', function(evt){
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    var $showingParent = $(this).parent('.showing');
                    $showingParent.slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });

        };

        var assignBehaviourToMenuContainer = function($in_target){

            $in_target.find('.menuContainer').on('click', function(evt){
                evt.stopPropagation();
                $(this).find(".showing").slideToggle("slow");
            });

        };

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var $myTarget = $('#myTargetContainer');
            var $slideToggleStatus = $('#slideToggleStatus');

            assignBehaviourToMenuItems($myTarget);
            assignBehaviourToMenuContainer($myTarget);


            window.onresize = function(){

                clearTimeout($.data(this, 'windowResiting'));

                $.data(this, 'windowResiting', setTimeout(function(){

                    if(window.outerWidth < 900){

                        if($myTarget.hasClass('disabled') == false){
                            //disable the click event
                            $myTarget.find('.trigger').off();
                            $myTarget.find('.menuContainer').off();

                            $myTarget.addClass('disabled');

                            $slideToggleStatus.text('diabled');

                        }

                    }
                    else{

                        if($myTarget.hasClass('disabled')){
                            //reassign the click events

                            assignBehaviourToMenuItems($myTarget);
                            assignBehaviourToMenuContainer($myTarget);

                            $myTarget.removeClass('disabled');

                            $slideToggleStatus.text('enabled');

                        }

                    }


                }, 50));

            };

            //trigger resize as soon as it loads.
            $(this).trigger('resize');



        });
```

```css
 body{
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue", Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        #myTargetContainer{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 200px;
            width: 240px;
            border: 2px solid lightblue;
            border-radius: 4px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #myTargetContainer.disabled{
        }

        #slideToggleStatus{
            color: green;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        #myTargetContainer.disabled #slideToggleStatus{
            color: red;
        }


        #myTargetContainer.larger{
            background-color: lightblue;
        }

        ul{
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        ul li{
            padding: 4px;
            border-bottom: 1px dashed white;
        }
        ul li:hover{
            background-color: gray;
        }

        .trigger{
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .menuContainer{
            min-height: 10px;
            border: 1px solid;
            background-color: #d3d3d3;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myTargetContainer">
    <div class="menuContainer">
        <ul class="showing">
            <li class="trigger">menu 1</li>
            <li class="trigger">menu 2</li>
            <li class="trigger">menu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>
        slideToggle is <span id="slideToggleStatus">enabled</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply MFAL.unfortunately neither of these is having the desired effect

Comment: make sure to stop event propagation if you have nested elements triggering click events.

Comment: forgive me if i've misunderstood MFAL but in the code snippet the menu closes when clicked no matter what the viewport size. i still struggle with some of the syntax when it comes to jquery so i may have missed something

Comment: in my example I am not checking specifically for view port size to disable the click event. I am checking for the status of the drop down list value. I was only proving that you can disable based on "some" parameter. I can provide you with a more specific example based on viewport size. Can you tell me what it the max size

Comment: thanks MFAL I appreciate the help.it would be based on max-width 900px as i've started with desktop size and then scaled down so i only want the script to run when the viewport goes below 900px wide.i've spent hours scouring for an answer to this problem but there doesn't seem to be a definitive solution